# jquery submit input and textareas at the same time

Tags: jquery

The code below saves all the Input Fields.  If I change the word "INPUT" to "TEXTAREA" it will save the textarea text boxes, is there a way to change the code to save all the input fields and the textarea fields at the same time, as opposed to running through the code twice?

```
// JQUERY: Run .autoSubmit() on all INPUT fields within form
$(function(){
$('#ajax-form INPUT').autoSubmit();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#ajax-form input, #ajax-form textarea').autoSubmit();
```

Or even better, use the [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) which matches `input`, `textarea` and `select`:

```
$('#ajax-form :input').autoSubmit();
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery allows multiple selectors, using a comma.

```
$('#ajax-form INPUT, #ajax-form textarea').autoSubmit();
```

Or, if you're feeling spicy, you can give the selector some context:

```
$('input, textarea', '#ajax-form').autoSubmit();
```

That will look for `input` and `textarea` only within `#ajax-form`